# Убрать номер порта из адресной строки 2083

Tags: node.js, https, cloudflare

Было создано приложение на node js. Приложение работает на https протоколе (cloudflare). После переноса его на доменное имя работает только с портом. Прим: `my-domain.com:2083`.Возможно ли как-то убрать порт из адресной строки? Приложение запускается не локально.

Comment: Слушать правильный порт. 443 если у вас https или 80 если http

Comment: Но вообще непонятно при чём тут клаудфлэр

Comment: Смотрите в настройки вашего веб-сервера, cloudflare тут ни при чем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, действительно, проблема состояла в использование порта 2083, который рекомендовал cloudflare. После изменения на 443 все стало нормально.